# Marklogic server 10.0-8.3-amd64 installed in Windows 10 system. Cannot start the Marklogic Server

Tags: marklogic

I have installed Marklogic server 10.0-8.3 AMD(64) in my windows 10 system.
However after the successful installation I am not able to start the Marklogic server.

When I do `-> Start->Right click on Start Marklogic Server-> Run as Administrator`
It prompts a window asking user access control - Do you allow an unknown app to make changes in your system. I click on YES.

But after that nothing happens in the screen. I cannot see any app running.

Can you please help, or if anybody has faced the same issue please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You interface with MarkLogic via web interfaces or REST APIs.  No application will visibly launch on your screen. The next step after install and starting the MarkLogic service is to go to http://localhost:8001 and continue the configuration.

https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/installation/procedures#id_60220

Comment: Thanks a lot @David Ennes. I can now open the server in my localhost.

Comment: @rashmita no problem. Glad it helped.